# Turn off Visual Studio reference highlighting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to turn off Visual Studio token reference highlighting for JavaScript (even through a hack?)

I am aware of how to turn it off for C# following this guide (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349251(v=vs.100).aspx), looks like there is no option available similar in the JavaScript tab, seems like a big oversight.

It's pretty annoying, and too much flickering occurs for my liking, especially when trying to duplicate lines then renaming, particularly working with a lot of attribute names in JSON notation or when you're moving your arrow keys across a shared object which is shown on many lines.

Eg.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is available for all the languages. JS is one of them. As a workaround, and if you don't mind disabling for the other languages as well, why not change the Highlighing color to match your Editor's background color. Unfortunately this not available for a specific language, but common for the editor.
By doing this, it would be the same effect as if you were to turn off the Highlight references. Below is from the same MSDN post you mentioned in your question.

> To change the reference highlighting color
>
> On the Tools menu, click Options.
>
> In the Options dialog box, expand Environment, and then click Fonts
>   and Colors.
>
> In the Show settings for box, click Text Editor.
>
> In the Display items list, click Highlighted Reference.
>
> In the Item background box, click the appropriate color.

Comment: Ok good suggestion, I was hoping I could stop the processing entirely as it seems like there is a bit of CPU overhead, but this is the next best thing. Thanks Spock.

Comment: I used this method to turn off reference highlighting in java too.